# Can not get certain programs to "show" up

Tags: 12.04

I am having trouble getting applications to "show" when selecting them from the sidebar. By "show" I mean when I click Ubuntu One, Ubuntu Software Center etc the applications start but are not visible on my screen. The only programs I can actually start are LibreOffice, Chromium and other browsers, Home folder

If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I can see they are running and when I select the program (tab to them while holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd>), the apps won't switch. I can not figure out why they are not visibly showing up. This seems to have happened after trying to update Nvidia drivers. I've tried to open Terminal and remove the update but Terminal will not allow me to type any commands.

I'm on 12.04 LTS if anyone has any thoughts as to what may be going on that would be great. This seems to be vague information but I don't know how else to capture the issue. Maybe I can provide screenshots that would be more helpful (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Login into virtual console(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then run the below commands,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Just figured out what the problem was. The display settings were picking up my Vizio TV as active and that is why this issue was occurring. I've disabled the second display and that fixed the issue.

Comment: plz post it as an answer.